# Cannot initialize the indexer process Magento 1.7

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.7

Okay so I just imported and edit an online store that we have setup with about 2500 products after I imported the CSV file and now I cannot Reindex the site and i am getting the following errors:

Cannot initialize the indexer process.

I tried running this command in phpMyAdmin but still didn't work

```
DELETE cpop.* FROM catalog_product_option_price AS cpop
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
ON cpo.option_id = cpop.option_id
WHERE
cpo.type = 'checkbox' OR
cpo.type = 'radio' OR
cpo.type = 'drop_down';

DELETE cpotp.* FROM catalog_product_option_type_price AS cpotp
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS cpotv
ON cpotv.option_type_id = cpotp.option_type_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
ON cpotv.option_id = cpo.option_id
WHERE
cpo.type <> 'checkbox' AND
cpo.type <> 'radio' AND
cpo.type <> 'drop_down';
```

Comment: Have you removed the lock files `var/locks` and tried again?  If that doesn't work, try Magento's Database Repair Tool --> http://www.magentocommerce.com/download  ..  and then remove the locks from `var/lock`  ..  Sounds like you may have a corrupted table or a stuck file ..

Comment: I did try that yesterday, I am trying to figure out how to use the repair tool but I am having a hard trime, I added this to the end of my .htaaccess file  

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %(REMOTE_ADDR) !^127\.0\.0\.1$
 RewriteRule !503.php /503.php [L]

Comment: this is the part that is confusing me too:Clone it as new database on the same server. Let’s call it “database2”
Create an empty database (”database3”)
Either copy your entire Magento folder (without cache and sessions) into a new one and install there into “database3” (By editing local.xml with credentials for the newly created “database3”);